# How to limit sign up emails to just .edu?

Tags: html, css, ruby, email, authentication

I'm currently creating a site that I would like to have users only be able to sign up to with just emails that end in .edu. As in, in order to sign up for this site, you need to have a .edu email. How would I be able to create that limitation?

Thank you!

Comment: Note this is highschool level string problem.

Comment: Check on client side and server side with string routines. Besides checking for the top-level domain on the email, do you need to make sure the .edu email address is a valid email address that someone actually owns?

Comment: @ Sam M Yes I do. in fact, i'd like to actually limit it perhaps to a list of acceptable domains, not just ones that end in .edu come to think of it. For example, I only allow college.edu, college2.edu, and collegemail.edu. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to solve this in a Rails app would be to add a simple [format validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#format) to your User model that allows only addresses with a specific pattern:

```
# in your user model
validates :email, format: { with: /\.edu\z/, message: "only allows .org addresses" }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a form, make a function that executes on form submit.

```
<form id="email" onsubmit="checkEmail()">
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email-input"/>
</form>
```

For the script:

```
function checkEmail(){
  var text = document.getElementById('email').value;
  if(text.indexOf('.edu') === text.length-4){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

The script checks if the email contains `.edu` at the very end of the input. If so, it returns `true` to carry on with submission. Otherwise, it returns `false`, and the form does not submit.

**EDIT** Case was given of `throwaway.edu@gmail.com`, as well as `.edu.com`, etc. Can handle this now.

Comment: throwaway.edu@gmail.com ?

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions. You can easily check to make sure it's a valid email and it's only a .edu email using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

use the `include?` method

```
email = "test.test@email.edu"
if email.include? ".edu"
  // do something in here
end
```